# How can I detect country where app is running?

Tags: coronasdk

Is there a easy way to detect in which country app is running?

I know that I can check IP of client, but I would like to know if there is a easier way to get that info. No location necessary, only country.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would think you would use the GPS to determine that.  You can't trust IP addresses because it could be routed through a proxy or something giving you false information.

Rob

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think it looks little "fishy" when game asks players for location. I need to determine country to choose which ad provider to use

Comment: Rob, does this system.getPreference( "locale", "country" ) require any permissions from player?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  But it tells you what country their device is set for, not what country are they in.  If I were to travel to Europe for instance, my phone would still return "United States" I think.